# Nginx with multiple conf file each with different server

Tags: nginx

Is it ok to create many .conf files under conf.d directory, with each .conf file having unique server name.

for example
cd $NGINX_HOME/conf.d

files under the directory are test.conf, test2.conf

### test.conf

server {
  server_name tst1
  location / {
 ...
 }

}

### test2.conf

server {
  server_name tst2
  location /{ 
 ...
 }
 }

Answer (score 2):

I would look at `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` for `include` statements. If you see `include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;` then it should work.

Another convention is to put them in `/etc/nginx/sites-available/` named by the sites' domain names. Then add symlinks to each of them in `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/`. If you try this, make sure you have `include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*` in your `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`.